# How can I rotate element with javascript like flip card

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have a problem with css rotate element from front to back with javascript. But I can't understand what is my mistake.

This is my basic HTML code. There is nothing wrong thing in here, but I  don't know how rotate element works.

I want to rotate from front to back but it doesn't work. I want to create card that can rotate from front to back. When I want to click card, it should rotate around itself. But I can't do it.

**Code**

```js
const game = document.querySelector(".game");

const nums = [];

var generateNumber = () => {
  for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
}

function displayNumbers() {
  generateNumber();
  for (let i of nums) {
    const card = `<div class="card" onclick="flipCard(this)">
                    <div class="front">
                      <img src="/images/qmark.jpg" width="50px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <h2>${i}</h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>`
    game.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", card);
  }
}

displayNumbers();

function flipCard(elm) {
  elm.classList.toggle("card-flip")
}
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #444;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

.card-flip {
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back,
.front {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <header>
    <h1>Card Game</h1>
    <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
  </header>
  <div class="game"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS rotate rotates it on the flat plane of the page, like turning a sheet of paper on a desk. I have the feeling you're asking for a more 3D solution, which will involve Javascript and possibly an animation plugin.

Comment: where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the back and the front of the card, then flip the container

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".btn-rotate");
const card = document.querySelector(".card");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

if (card.className === "card back") {
        card.className = "card front";
  } else {
    card.className = "card back";
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .front {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.card .back {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card front">
  <div class="front">Front</div>
  <div class="back">Back</div>
</div>

<br/>

<button class="btn-rotate">Flip</button>
```